Create JPA CriteriaBuilder based on search field type LocalDate
I'm trying to create single org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification class to handle all fields of the Entity that are of String or LocalDate types.
I'm getting the Java type of the field as below
@Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Person> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                
        Path<String> field = root.<String>get(this.columnName);
        Class<? extends String> javaType = field.getJavaType();

Here the javaType is "class java.time.LocalDate" for LocalDate field. I just need to create an if condition to check if javaType is equal to java.time.LocalDate. I compare String field as below.
if(javaType == String.class) {
        return criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(root.<String>get(this.columnName)), "%"+this.searchTerm.toLowerCase()+"%");
    }

But creating comparisons like below gets a warning or an error.
if(javaType.equals(java.time.LocalDate.class.toString())) // Unlikely argument type for equals(): String seems to be unrelated to Class<capture#5-of ? extends String>

if(javaType.equals(java.time.LocalDate.class)) // Incompatible operand types Class<capture#5-of ? extends String> and Class<LocalTime>

How to create a comparison for this javaType Object which extends String to LocalDate

When you are calling root.<String>get(this.columnName); you are telling hibernate to process that column as a String even if that is not that type. You should greate a generic specification, that can manage the field using its specific type, for example like this:
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyEntityGenericSpecification<T> implements Specification<MyEntity> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 5142379341911056096L;

  private final String columnName;
  private final T searchTerm;

  @Override
  public Predicate toPredicate(
      Root<MyEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

    Path<T> field = root.<T>get(this.columnName);
    Class<? extends T> javaType = field.getJavaType();

    if (javaType.isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
      return criteriaBuilder.like(
          criteriaBuilder.lower(root.<String>get(this.columnName)),
          "%" + this.searchTerm.toString().toLowerCase() + "%");
    } else if (javaType.isAssignableFrom(LocalDate.class)) {
      return criteriaBuilder.equal(field, searchTerm);
    }

    return criteriaBuilder.and();
  }
}

I tested this in a simple junit class and seems to generate correctly the sql statemens. I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but I believe that this may be a starting point.
